# Pandas variable numbers of columns to binary matrix

Tags: python, csv, matrix, pandas

I am currently working with a data set(csv file) which doesn't have a fixed number of columns. however, I want to convert it to a binary matrix which have a fixed number of columns.

as an example, current data set is like this(no headers),

```
a,b,x,z,y
b,e,w,t,u,o,s,z,i
z,o,w
o,p,w,z,a
```

I want this to be converted to below (first row is the header)

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z

1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1
```

The main problem I am experiencing is the varied number of columns in data set. The pseudo code or the logic I was considering is this

```
header=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]
data_frame=csv file
df=new data frame
for each row in data_frame:
      for each item in row:
          create pandas Series 
          if item in header:
             append '1' to Series
          else:
             append '0' to Series
       append series to df
```

Finally the matrix should be written in to another csv file.

I have fair knowledge in python but not in pandas. Therefore, I am kindly asking someone to give me some help with this point as I cant seems to be find a way to do this. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `pd.get_dummies()`.

```
import pandas as pd

# read your csv data, separate must not be ',', for example, set tab `\t`
# =======================================================================
# I just read from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, sep='\t')

df
                   0
0          a,b,x,z,y
1  b,e,w,t,u,o,s,z,i
2              z,o,w
3          o,p,w,z,a

# step 1
# =========================
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda group: pd.Series(group.values.ravel().tolist()[0].split(',')))

df1

0  0    a
   1    b
   2    x
   3    z
   4    y
1  0    b
   1    e
   2    w
   3    t
   4    u
       ..
   7    z
   8    i
2  0    z
   1    o
   2    w
3  0    o
   1    p
   2    w
   3    z
   4    a
dtype: object


# step 2
# =========================
pd.get_dummies(df1).groupby(level=0).agg(max)

   a  b  e ...  x  y  z
0  1  1  0 ...  1  1  1
1  0  1  1 ...  0  0  1
2  0  0  0 ...  0  0  1
3  1  0  0 ...  0  0  1

[4 rows x 13 columns]

# step 3, to_csv()
# =========================
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm and only few problems remain.  Actually the output looked like

`
   0_a  0_b  0_e ...  0_x  0_y  0_z
0  1  1  0 ...  1  1  1
1  0  1  1 ...  0  0  1
2  0  0  0 ...  0  0  1
3  1  0  0 ...  0  0  1
`
This can be easily fixed i think. Another problem is varied unique value list for header. 
`pp=pd.unique(df.values.ravel())` provides 381 unique value(this is the correct one) but my result only gave me 294 columns. what could be the problem?

Comment: I figured out the problem.  My initial dataset in in csv comma separated format. i have to merge them in to the same cell before applying this method. Or is there are way to marge the columns in pandas?