# What is a very general way to read-in .csv in Python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, input

I have a .csv file with rows with multiple columns lengths.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(infile, header=None)
```

returns the

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 8, saw 8
```

error. I know I can use the

```
names=my_cols
```

option in the read_csv call, but surely there has to be something more 'pythonic' than that??   Also, this is not a duplicate question, since

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

causes lines to be skipped (which is not desired). The .csv looks like::

```
Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie,Frank,Hannah
Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie
Caroline,Hannah
David,,Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie
Ernie,Anne,Beth,Frank,George
Frank,Anne,Caroline,Hannah
George,
Hannah,Anne,Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie,Frank,George
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without actually seeing what your csv's actually look like, the error could be because you have a mismatch between the column names and actual columns, you have embedded commas, your separator isn't a comma etc..

Comment: What do you expect your `df` to look like?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the question above, since " error_bad_lines=False" causes lines to be skipped. I don't want that behaviour.

Comment: So what are you expecting here? You want `NaN` where you have missing values? You want to keep all rows? For instance it looks like you don't have a consistent number of entries, you'd have to parse the csv to determine the maximum number of columns and then read it in without a header

Comment: the df should be an e.g. r by c matrix, where r is the total number of rows and c is the number of columns from the row with the most columns. NaNs where there is no data

Comment: Parsing the csv I think is fine. Just seems weird to me given Pandas flexibility, it can't automatically figure this out.

Comment: Why should it? Why should the library have to parse the entire csv first and then on the second pass construct the df knowing the maximum number of columns? That seems to be an unreasonable assumption and something that isn't common enough to need

Comment: Because data is messy and/or incomplete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, somewhat inspired by this related question: [Pandas variable numbers of columns to binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493880/pandas-variable-numbers-of-columns-to-binary-matrix)

So read in the csv but override the separator to a tab so it doesn't try to split the names:

```
In[7]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie,Frank,Hannah
Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie
Caroline,Hannah
David,,Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie
Ernie,Anne,Beth,Frank,George
Frank,Anne,Caroline,Hannah
George,
Hannah,Anne,Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie,Frank,George"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\t', header=None)
df

Out[7]: 
                                                   0
0              Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie,Frank,Hannah
1                          Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie
2                                    Caroline,Hannah
3                    David,,Anne,Beth,Caroline,Ernie
4                       Ernie,Anne,Beth,Frank,George
5                         Frank,Anne,Caroline,Hannah
6                                            George,
7  Hannah,Anne,Beth,Caroline,David,Ernie,Frank,Ge...
```

We can now use `str.split` with `expand=True` to expand the names into their own columns:

```
In[8]:
df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

Out[8]: 
          0         1         2         3         4       5      6       7
0      Anne      Beth  Caroline     Ernie     Frank  Hannah   None    None
1      Beth  Caroline     David     Ernie      None    None   None    None
2  Caroline    Hannah      None      None      None    None   None    None
3     David                Anne      Beth  Caroline   Ernie   None    None
4     Ernie      Anne      Beth     Frank    George    None   None    None
5     Frank      Anne  Caroline    Hannah      None    None   None    None
6    George                None      None      None    None   None    None
7    Hannah      Anne      Beth  Caroline     David   Ernie  Frank  George
```

So just to be clear modify your `read_csv` line to this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(infile, header=None, sep='\t')
```

and then do the `str.split` as above

Comment: What happened to `(1, 3)`?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal those are missing values so it looks like they are treated as empty/blank strings they could be replaced with `None` easily but thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Sorry, I was triggered by the inconsistency. :)

Comment: Yeah, this (I think!) works for what I want. It is interesting that one might well want to differentiate between empty/blank strings and NaNs/Nones. But that's a separate issue(!!)

Answer (score 1):

One can do some manipulation with the csv before using pandas.

```
# load data into list
with open('new_data.txt', 'r') as fil:
    data = fil.readlines()

# remove line breaks from string entries
data = [ x.replace('\r\n', '') for x in data]
data = [ x.replace('\n', '') for x in data]

# calculate the number of columns
total_cols = max([x.count(',') for x in data])

# add ',' to end of list depending on how many are needed
new_data = [x + ','*(total_cols-x.count(',')) for x in data]

# save data
with open('save_data.txt', 'w') as outp:
    outp.write('\n'.join(new_data))

# read it in as you did.
pd.read_csv('save_data.txt', header=None)
```

This is some rough python, but should work. I'll clean this up when I have time.

Or use the other answer, it's neat as it is.

Comment: I have no problem having a csv_manipulation function before reading in the data to the main program! ;-)