# Pandas Read_CSV issue with "|" delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I'm having a delimiter problem when reading a text file into Python using Pandas read_csv.

My file has a vertical bar `|` delimiter.

When I use `sep='|'` I get a parsing error.

When I omit `sep='|'`, allowing the python engine sniffer to work instead of the C engine, all fields are returned into a single dataframe column without being delimited - like this:

[image]

Insights appreciated

Comment: What error do you get? What does the file look like?

Comment: If the problem is that there are a variable number of columns, then see [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645179/190597).

Comment: @thanks unutbu - that was exactly the problem and EdChum's answer solved it perfectly