# How to read file when the words are separated by "|" (PSV)?

Tags: python, file-io, pipe, separator

In Python, I have a file which the words are separated by `|`, for example: `city|state|zipcode`. My file reader is unable to separate the words. Also, I want my file reader to start on line 2 rather than line 1. How do I get my file reader to separate the words?

```
import os
import sys

def file_reader(path, num_fields, seperator = ',', header = False):
    try:
        fp = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Unable to open file.")
    else:
        with fp:
            for n, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
                fields = line.rstrip('/n').split(seperator)
                if len(fields) != num_fields:
                    raise ValueError("Unable to read file.")
                elif n == 1 and header:
                    continue
                else:
                    yield tuple([f.strip() for f in fields])
```

Comment: I just tried your exact code, and seems to work fine for me. Could you elaborate on the error? Maybe provide a sample of where you actually call `file_reader`. I did something like `for x in file_reader(filename, 5, '|', False): print(x)` and it works fine.

Comment: Is it called correctly with "seperator" set to "|"?

Comment: It's working now, Michael is right, all I had to do was put "|".

Comment: And you need `header = True` to skip the first line.

Comment: This is called **PSV (Pipe-Separated Value)**, as opposed to CSV. Can you use `pandas read_csv`? If so this is a duplicate of [Pandas Read_CSV issue with “|” delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652574/pandas-read-csv-issue-with-delimiter)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind to use existing framework, you can use pandas. You can skip first row using skiprows=1 and change the separator using sep='|'

```
# load pandas
import pandas as pd

# read file as pandas dataframe
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=1,sep='|')
print(dataframe)
```

To install pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

Pandas documentation for read_csv:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Other option is to use csv reader to read your psv file:

```
import csv

with open('file.psv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    next(csv_reader, None)  # read once to skip the header once

    for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[1:-1]` (I think) you can select a sub array which starts after the first value of the array, which in the case of a file, should mean you get every line except the first.

Comment: There is no array (or list) here, it is just an iterator.

Comment: My bad. I'm new, so I honestly am gonna be pretty dumb. Just trying to help where I can.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to read from second line you can change your code from: `for n, line in enumerate(fp, 1)` to `for n, line in enumerate(fp[1:], 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ultra shoddy ++ option to skip enumerating the first value: make a boolean value initialised to true, and then add an if statement at the start of your for loop which tests if this boolean value is true. Inside this `if` statement, set the value to false, and then pass a `continue`

Something like:

```
b = True
for k, v in enumerator:
  if b:
    b = False
    continue
  # Some code
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you request, the function is fine, and it is important to call it with the correct arguments, and make them different from default.

From the code, the default behavior is to use `,` as a separator, and to not skip the first line of the file. In order to actually split with `|` and skip the first line (i.e. a header), then we will set `seperator='|'` and `header = True` when we call it.

```
# Function is fine, leave as-is
#
def file_reader(path, num_fields, seperator = ',', header = False):
    try:
        fp = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Unable to open file.")
    else:
        with fp:
            for n, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
                fields = line.rstrip('/n').split(seperator)
                if len(fields) != num_fields:
                    raise ValueError("Unable to read file.")
                elif n == 1 and header:
                    continue
                else:
                    yield tuple([f.strip() for f in fields])

# Example file afile.txt contains these lines:
# alfa|beta|gamma|delta
# 1|2|3|4
# a|b|c|d

# here we call the function:

filename = 'afile.txt'
for x in file_reader(filename, 4, '|', True):  #note the separator and header
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We will divide the work into 3 steps reading the file, store each line of the file in a list, separate the list

**Reading File**
in python you can easily read a file using 'open' command as follows:

```
fp=open("file.txt",'r')
```

**Reading each line separately**
to read the file as lines you can use 'readlines' command as follows:

```
lines=fp.readline():
```

this will return the content of the file as a list, in which each record represent a line. You can also read a specific line by passing the number of the line `fp.readline(5)`

--> For more info check [reading files in python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)
**Separating the Content**
To separate the Strings by '|' use the 'split' method:

```
for item in lines:
    res=item.split('|')
    #do what you want with res
```